# How do I specify a Pointcut which includes all public methods in a package hierarchy but excludes some specfic methods?

Tags: aspectj

I have the following simple Aspect.

```
package com.example.foo.aspects;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class TimingProfiler
{
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TimingProfiler.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(String *.toString())"
            + " || execution(int *.hashCode())"
            + " || execution(boolean *.equals(Object))"
            + " || execution(int *.getId())"
            + " || execution(String *.getName())")
    public void whatIDontWantToMatch(){}

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.example.foo..*(..))")
    public void whatIWantToMatch(){}

    @Pointcut("whatIWantToMatch() && ! whatIDontWantToMatch()")
    public void allIWantToMatch(){}

    @Around("allIWantToMatch()")
    public Object aroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        Signature signature = joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
        logger.info("Entering method " + signature);

        Object returnValue = joinPoint.proceed();

        logger.info("Leaving method " + signature);

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I get the following message during compilation, however.

```
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(com.example.foo.bar.baz.snack.SnackIdentifier com.example.foo.bar.baz.snack.Snack.getId())' in Type 'com.example.foo.bar.baz.snack.Snack' (Snack.java:78) advised by around advice from 'com.example.foo.aspects.TimingProfiler' (foo-profiler-lib.jar!TimingProfiler.class(from TimingProfiler.java))
```

And when I run the code I get log messages from the methods I am trying to exclude.

How do I correctly include all of the public methods found in the `com.example.foo` package while excluding some specific ones?

Comment: This is related to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835547/how-to-exclude-methods-from-aspectj, but my code isn't working based on just the advice found there.

Answer (score 0):

I was overlooking the fact that my PointCut was excluding `int getId()` and the methods I was seeing show up in the output were `SnackIdentifier getId()`.  The correct answer to this question is to pay attention.