# AspectJ adding pointcut execution for onCreate() methods

Tags: android, aspectj

I wanted to write a common pointcut execution for my Android application that has 3 activities that will pointcut only `onCreate()` methods in all the 3 activities. How do I write this pointcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

```
pointcut GIVE_IT_A_NAME() : execution(void Activity.onCreate(..));
```

or, if you want to get all the `Activity` subclasses, you add a `+`:

```
pointcut GIVE_IT_A_NAME() : execution(void Activity+.onCreate(..));
```

Then, you can use the pointcut for example:

```
before() : GIVE_IT_A_NAME() {
    // do something
}
```

You can also use `after()`, it depends what you're trying to achieve.

As you said, you need it for your classes, in fact, please notice that you cannot inject code in Android core classes because they are not part of your APK but provided on the device.

If you want to be sure to inject your classes only, you could add some conditions to the pointcut definition:

```
pointcut GIVE_IT_A_NAME() : execution(void *.onCreate(..))
&& within(YOUR_MAIN_PACKAGE_NAME.*)
&& this(android.app.Activity+);
```

So the pointcut must be within that specific package name and the class type must be `android.app.Activity` or a subclass. Of course, if you're using the Android Support Library, you need to change this last condition.

Comment: Great! I'm not sure how you're injecting code, but I always find easy during the development, to add the -showweaveinfo parameter to the AspectJ compiler, so I can see which on classes and methods my pointcuts have been applied to or if they haven't been at all (so probably an issue in the pointcut definition).

Comment: I had 1 more doubt.I have other pointcut too that pointcuts each method including onCreate(). Now I wanted 2 pointcuts - 1 for onCreate() only and another for all other methods except onCreate(). How do I have these 2 pointcuts?

Comment: I should see the code or at least know more about "all other methods", so the best option for you is to create a new question for this issue, which is different. One advice I can give you is to combine different pointcuts with boolean expression. It's hard to write it in a comment, so look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835547/how-to-exclude-methods-from-aspectj

Comment: Thank you but I asked a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437847/aspectj-writing-2-separate-pointcuts-one-for-oncreate-and-other-for-rest-of-me

Comment: hwo to get only subclass without superclass