# AspectJ writing 2 separate pointcuts one for onCreate() and other for rest of methods

Tags: android, aspectj

I am using AspectJ for Android and I am having a requirement of writing 2 pointcuts one which does pointcut execution for `onCreate()` and other for rest of the methods in the Android app that excludes `onCreate()`.

Currently my pointcut for methods is also injecting onCreate() which I dont want to happen. It is like this -

```
pointcut methodCalls():
          execution(* com.hello..*(..)) && !within(com.retro.Tester);
```

Tester.aj is my Aspect file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 pointcuts, one for `onCreate()` method and `methodcalls()`, you should rely on pointcuts boolean expression:

```
pointcut yourOnCreatePointcut() : execution(INSERT_YOUR_CONDITIONS);
pointcut methodCalls(): execution(* com.hello..*(..)) && !within(com.retro.Tester);
pointcut GIVE_IT_A_PROPER_NAME() : methodCalls() && ! yourOnCreatePointcut();
```

Then, add `before()` and/or `after()` only for the `yourOnCreatePointcut()` and `GIVE_IT_A_PROPER_NAME()` pointcuts, not for `methodCalls()`.